# Realizar uma busca por data em uma coluna timestamp utilizando spring data

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data

Estou tentando realizar um busca apenas pela data atual em uma coluna *timestamp*, ou seja sem informar as horas e sim apenas a data.

Modelo:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "data")
private Date date;
```

Atualmente utilizo o Spring Data para realizar a consulta.

Classe de serviço:

```
public List<Order> findByDate(){
    return orderRepository.findByDate(new Date());
}
```

Repositório Spring Data:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
    List<Order> findByDate(Date date); 
}
```

O problema que a `query` é feita levando em consideração o timestamp atual com valores de hora minuto e segundo e quero que o `select` seja feita apenas selecionando os registos de data atual.

Select com o binding de exemplo:

```
SELECT 
    order0_.id AS id1_1_,
    order0_.data AS data2_1_,
    order0_.pedido AS pedido3_1_,
    order0_.pagamento AS pagament4_1_,
    order0_.telefone AS telefone5_1_,
    order0_.status AS status6_1_,
    order0_.total AS total7_1_,
    order0_.usuario AS usuario8_1_
FROM
    spring_admin.pedidos_zuhause order0_
WHERE
    order0_.data = ?;
```

**binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Wed Sep 20 10:15:35 BRT 2017]**

Eu sei que via *MySQL* consigo fazer isso utilizando a função `date()`, mas como posso fazer isso pelo *hibernate*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como a coluna em banco armazena também informações que não apenas dia/mês/ano você tem que fazer com que a query gerada considere isto.

Uma forma de fazer isto é buscando por compras com `date` *between* o início e término do dia. A consulta no seu repositório ficaria assim:

```
List<Order> findByDateBetween(final Date start, final Date end);
```

A chamada no seu service seria algo como isto:

```
public List<Order> findByDate(){
    final Date start = // recupera o início do dia;
    final Date end = // recupera o fim do dia;
    return orderRepository.findByDate(start, end);
}
```

Veja aqui formas de obter datas de início e fim do dia: [How to obtain the start time and end time of a day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308356/how-to-obtain-the-start-time-and-end-time-of-a-day)

Como você mesmo citou funções nativas do SGBD podem ser usadas. O Spring Data fornece outros meios para criação de queries, como [`@Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) e [`QueryDSL`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl), além do já suportado por padrão pela JPA.